# Let $A$ be a square matrix, show that $A + A^T$ and $AA^T$ are symmetric matrices.

Tags: matrices

I know that a symmetric matrix is equal to it's transpose. 
I've also realised that, if they are symmetric,

$$A=AT$$

$$AA^T=A^TA^T$$

But I know I'm missing the main link. Maybe I need to find a property of square matrixes that means the above are symmetric?

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!!
Thanks

Comment: There exactly are you having problems checking that those two matrices are symmetric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some properties of transpose are $$(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T$$
$$(AB)^T=B^TA^T$$

$$(A^T)^T=A$$

Using these properties, we conclude that

$$(A+A^T)^T=A^T+(A^T)^T=A^T+A$$

$$(AA^T)^T=(A^T)^TA^T=AA^T$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(A+A^T)^T＝A^T＋(A^T)^T＝A^T＋A$$

$$(AA^T)^T＝(A^T)^TA^T＝AA^T$$